# Find list of users with no assets from two tables in MSSQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Sorry, I am quite new to SQL and I'm trying to do the following.

I have two tables, "asset" and "users", structured as follows:

**users table**

```
userName  fullName        department   location
aanderson Andrew Anderson Sales        South Wing
bjackson  Bernice Jackson Marketing    Ontario
csmith    Chris Smith     Supply Chain South Wing
etc.
```

**asset table**

```
userName  srpNum category  model  etc.
aanderson 004120 Laptop    E5520
csmith    001030 Laptop    E5550
```

I want to return all users with no assets.  So from the above I want to return `bjackson` as she has no assets listed in the asset table.

How do I do this?  I think I have to join the two tables in my query.  I have tried something like `select userName from users, asset where count(*) = 0` but this apparently isn't the appropriate syntax.

Thanks very much!

Comment: Hint:  `NOT EXISTS` or `NOT IN` would be appropriate.

Comment: Hm, okay.  I just tried `select userName from users where NOT EXISTS (select userName from asset)` but that doesn't return anything.

Comment: This worked: `select userName from users as u where NOT EXISTS (select userName from asset as a where a.userName=u.userName)`

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I found that worked:

```
select userName
from users u
where NOT EXISTS (select userName from asset a where a.userName = u.userName)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a join you can try this:

SELECT distinct u.username FROM users as u left join asset as a On u.username=a.username WHERE a.username is null